# Joining 3 tables to count the score of a Match

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I have 3 tables.

```
Team
  TeamId        Team 
   1       Manchester United
   2       Arsenal 
   3       Liverpool

Match    
 MatchId HomeTeamId AwayTeamId  MatchStartDate
 3         1           2          2/2/2015
 8         3           1          6/2/2015

Score
 ScoreId MatchId TeamId      ScorTime
 1         3      1      2/2/2015 12:30:00
 2         3      2      2/2/2015 12:35:00
 3         3      1      2/2/2015 12:38:00
 4         8      1      6/2/2015 12:45:00
 5         8      1      6/2/2015 12:49:00
```

I wanted something like

```
 MatchId HomeTeam            HomeTeamScore  AwayTeam     AwayTeamScore MatchDate
 3         Manchester United     2           Arsenal         1        2/2/2015
 8         Liverpool             0        Manchester United  2        6/2/2015
```

I have tried this but I  am not getting corrent counts.

```
SELECT COUNT(hscore.MatchId) AS HomeScore
     , COUNT(ascore.MatchId) AS AwayScore 
FROM Match 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Score AS hscore 
         ON Match.AwayTeamId = hscore.TeamId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score AS ascore 
         ON Match.HomeTeamId = ascore.TeamId
```

Comment: Well, you don't tell us what's wrong with your results, so I'll take a guess.  Try using `count (distinct hscore.MatchId)`.

Comment: Why did you use a right outer join and a left one? Shouldn't they both be left one as you only care about the score if the Match exists.

Comment: Is it a typo that your hscore alias (and therefore your HomeScore result) is using the AwayTeamId and vice versa?    Or is that the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cross Apply to act like a function to get the Team Names and just sub select your scores..

```
SELECT  m.MatchId,
        ht.Team AS HomeTeam,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM Score s 
         WHERE s.MatchId = m.MatchId AND s.TeamId = ht.TeamId) AS HomeTeamScore,
        at.Team AS AwayTeam,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM Score s 
         WHERE s.MatchId = m.MatchId AND s.TeamId = at.TeamId) AS AwayTeamScore,
        m.MatchStartDate
FROM    Match m
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TeamID, Team FROM Team WHERE TeamId = m.HomeTeamId) ht
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TeamID, Team FROM Team WHERE TeamId = m.AwayTeamId) at
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bc67/2)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT Match.Matchid
    , COUNT(hscore.MatchId) AS HomeScore
    , COUNT(ascore.MatchId) AS AwayScore 
FROM Match  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score AS hscore 
         ON Match.HomeTeamId = hscore.TeamId AND Match.Matchid = hscore.Matchid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Score AS ascore 
         ON Match.AwayTeamId = ascore.TeamId AND Match.Matchid = ascore.Matchid
GROUP BY  Match.Matchid
```

If you want to add in the team names you will need to join to the team table twice as well but that can be an inner join.

Comment: i'm not seeing this right scores with this even though I thought it work too..   Sql Fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bc67/3

Comment: I used your joins but didn't notice that you you joined on away team to get the home team and vice versos. Check the revised version.

Comment: Left outer joins are not right for this case and the result will be wrong if there is atleast one data. In this case the count for MatchID 3 and Awayteamscore is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This should give what you want

`Select MatchID, 
H.Team as HomeTeam, 
HomeTeamScore = (Select Count(*) From Score Where MatchID = M.MatchID And TeamID = M.HomeTeamId),
A.Team as AwayTeam, 
AwayTeamScore = (Select Count(*) From Score Where MatchID = M.MatchID And TeamID = M.AwayTeamId),
MatchStartDate
From Match M
Inner Join Team H On M.HomeTeamId = H.TeamID
Inner Join Team A On M.AwayTeamId = A.TeamID`

Comment: I never recommend the use of a correlated subquery, they kill performance.

Comment: Yep, but it works and can be fine tuned for performance later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     m.MatchID
    ,ht.Team HomeTeam
    ,htscore.score HomeTeamScore
    ,at.Team AwayTeam
    ,atscore.score AwayTeamScore
    ,m.MatchStartDate MatchDate
FROM Match m
INNER JOIN Team ht ON m.HomeTeamID=ht.TeamID
INNER JOIN Team at ON m.AwayTeamID=at.TeamID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MatchID,TeamID,COUNT(*) score
    FROM Score
    GROUP BY MatchID,TeamID
) htscore ON htscore.MatchID=m.MatchID AND htscore.TeamID=ht.TeamID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MatchID,TeamID,COUNT(*) score
    FROM Score
    GROUP BY MatchID,TeamID
) atscore ON atscore.MatchID=m.MatchID AND atscore.TeamID=at.TeamID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version:

```
WITH Scores (MatchId, TeamId, cnt) AS (
  SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(*)
  FROM Score
  GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId
)
SELECT Match.Matchid,
       COALESCE(h.cnt, 0) AS HomeScore,
       COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) AS AwayScore 
FROM Match  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Scores h ON Match.MatchId = h.MatchId AND Match.HomeTeamId = h.TeamId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Scores a ON Match.MatchId = a.MatchId AND Match.AwayTeamId = a.TeamId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bc67)